# How do you say "Do you have any photos wearing it?"?

Tags: traduction

So, I like to shop second-hand online, and I've encountered many French sellers, and as such, how would one ask: "Do you have any photos wearing it?". It's probably a really basic question, but I can't find any examples. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any photos wearing it? can only mean: photos [in which you] are wearing it. **Avez-vous des photos oú vous le portez?** [le ou la].  Is that sentence the one you really mean as expressed in English for your online shopping?

Comment: Une variante : avez-vous une photo où l'on voit ces vêtements portés ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to say that. En voici quelques unes.

- En avez-vous des photos où on le voit porté par quelqu'un ?
- Avez-vous des photos d'un mannequin en train de le porter ?
- Est-ce que l'on peut voir en photo quelqu'un qui le porte ?
- Vous n'auriez pas des photos qui montrent à quoi ça ressemble quand on le porte ?

Comment: 1) Do you have photos where we see someone wearing it? 2) Do you have photos of a model wearing it? 3) Is there a photo where someone is wearing it? 4) You wouldn't have any photos that show what it looks like when it's being worn. would you? In fact, the English **as written by the OP** can only mean what I put in my comment above....

Comment: @Lambie I couldn't put it any better in English; I supposed that the OP's sentence was  less than ideal in expressing that idea, but that  what was meant was in fact what I wrote in French. In fact there is no "vous" in the translation: the subject of "wearing" is "photo" (nonsense).

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to say what someone means until they say  it. Or to reinvent the wheel for them. Plus, you didn't translate what is actually a perfectly good sentence in English even if the OP actually meant something else.

Comment: @Lambie I don't believe it is correct English; how do you parse this sentence?

Comment: I translated it in my comment. It is 100% grammatical and correct. **If it weren't, I'd be the first person to say it.**. Why don't you read my comment under the question? You didn't even bother, did you? C'est typique du language parlé. Une copine me montre une robe. Je lui dit: Do you have a photo [where you are] wearing it?

Comment: @Lambie This is not so; in fact you are the one that is not reading comments properly; in my last comment there is the mention of "vous": where would I have got it except in your comment? That pronoun in your translation is coming out of the blue; moreover no grammatical parsing seems proper. Since it is so plain to you that the sentence is correct you should readily have the parsing. Why not let us know, it should be no problem for you to do that in a few words.

Comment: Mais non.  Tu ne comprends pas l'anglais parlé à fond. Dans son versant parlé et courant. Voilà le vrai problème.  I already have given you the parse: Do you have a photo [where you are] wearing it? The where you are is **left out**. This is typical of spoken English. **Typical**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127148/discussion-between-lph-and-lambie).

Comment: Well, I didn't expect my question to be so controversial, ahah... Thank you both for your answers. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but I meant what @Lambie said: "Do you have a photo [where you are] wearing it?". Of course I didn't mean "what the photo is wearing", that wouldn't make any sense. So, to further clarify, I'll give context: whilst online shopping, people sometimes only put photos of the garment in question, but I like to see it worn, so that I can have a better idea of the fit, so I ask them if they have any photo of them wearing said garment. I hope I was a bit clearer now.

Comment: To be honest these propositions are all very valid and convey the general idea. I guess when buying something to a stranger on the web, you don't care about who is actually wearing it, it's just a matter of seeing it on somebody rather than lying flat on a table... Now asking the same question to a friend of course you're interested in how this friend looks like in this outfit...